# How to get data from nested object from firebase?

Tags: flutter, dart

So I'm currently following course flutter and here I'm trying to get some data from the nested object from firebase

this one call when fetching data

```
 final favoriteResponse = await http.get(url);
      final favoriteData = json.decode(favoriteResponse.body);
      final List<Product> loadedProducts = [];
      extractedData.forEach((prodId, prodData) {
        loadedProducts.add(Product(
          id: prodId,
          title: prodData['title'],
          description: prodData['description'],
          price: prodData['price'],
          isFavorite: favoriteData == null
              ? false
              : favoriteData[prodId]['isFavorite'] ?? false,
          imageUrl: prodData['imageUrl'],
        ));
        print(favoriteData[prodId]);
      });
      _items = loadedProducts;
      notifyListeners();
```

as you can see on the is favorite I want to get it from `favoritedata[prodId]['isFavorite]`, why I'm using it like that because if I print `favoritedata[prodId]` the result is `{'isFavorite':true}` so I call like this `favoritedata[prodId]['isFavorite]` that get of boolean data, but its give me an error like this:

```
/flutter (15722): Receiver: null
I/flutter (15722): Tried calling: []("isFavorite")
```

also, this one is for updating the value to the database

```
try {
      final response = await http.put(
        url,
        body: json.encode(
          {
            'isFavorite': isFavorite,
          },
        ),
      );

      if (response.statusCode >= 400) {
        _setFavValue(oldStatus);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      _setFavValue(oldStatus);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just checking for `favoriteData`  to not be null, but also `favoriteData[prodId]` could be null, so you need check that too. Change this

```
isFavorite: favoriteData == null
              ? false
              : favoriteData[prodId]['isFavorite'] ?? false,
```

to this:

```
isFavorite: favoriteData == null || favoriteData[prodId] == null
              ? false
              : favoriteData[prodId]['isFavorite'] ?? false,
```

Comment: This work but, I'm curious about what happened here could you please explain?